# Django SearchVector postgres searchvector not saving correct strings

Tags: django, postgresql, search

The postgres SearchVector in Django seems to be shortening my strings, I dont understand why. Ive shortened the code below to show what is happening.

I am querying a person object with a lastname that is added to the SearchVector.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
    self.model.objects.annotate(
                        search=SearchVector(
                            "last_name"
                        )
                ).filter(search__icontains="hjer").first().search
```

reults in: "'hjerp':1"

But the last_name is actually:

```
self.model.objects.annotate(
                    search=SearchVector(
                        "last_name"
                    )
                ).filter(search__icontains="hjer").first().last_name
```

'Hjerpe'

Why is the *e* not present in the search string? I would expect search above to show: "'hjerpe:1'"

Comment: I found that select to_tsvector('Hjerpe') in postgres results in "hjerp:1" as well. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the setting beeing sent in to the SearchVector, i changed:

```
self.model.objects.annotate(
                    search=SearchVector(
                        "last_name"
                    )
```

to

```
self.model.objects.annotate(
                    search=SearchVector(
                        "last_name", config="simple"
                    )
```

And the simple config does not do the smart stemming that the standard SearchVector does.

Comment: But what is the point of using a Search Vector on people's last names anyway?

Comment: @jjanes as stated in the original question i shortened the code to make the problem more visible, the real code has more attributes in the search vector.